# Android Studio: Opened old project and now have repeated runtime errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working through Udacity's Android Basics: User Input course. Previously everything worked fine, but I've opened up the project and now I get repeated runtime crashes. I haven't changed anything (that I'm aware of) from what was working before.

The crash occurs whenever I use increment() and decrement(). I went through the debugger and got a notification that there was an IDE error, so I'm not sure if this is a problem with Android Studio or an error of my own.

I'm stumped on how to understand this problem and would appreciate some help. Let me know if I need to add any more data to this post.

Copy of MainActivity.java, Logcat, build.gradle, activity_main.xml is below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

int quantity = 0;

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int price = calculatePrice();
    String priceMessage = createOrderSummary();
    displayMessage(priceMessage);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the '+' button is clicked.
 */
public void increment(View view) {
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the '-' button is clicked.
 */
public void decrement(View view) {
    quantity = quantity - 1;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method displays an order summary after hitting the 'order' button
 */
private String createOrderSummary() {
    String nameLine = "Name: Kaptain Kunal";
    String quantityLine = "Quantity: " + quantity;
    String totalLine = "Total: $ " + calculatePrice();
    String thankyouLine = "Thank you!";
    String orderSummary = nameLine + "\n" + quantityLine + "\n" + totalLine + "\n" + thankyouLine;
    return orderSummary;
}

/**
 * This method calculates the total cost of the order
 * @return correctPrice = quantity of coffee * cost of per cup
 */
private int calculatePrice() {
    int price = quantity * 5;
    return price;
}
/**
 * This method displays the given text on the screen.
 */
private void displayMessage(String message) {
    TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_tex_view);
    orderSummaryTextView.setText(message);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void displayQuantity(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(number);
}
}
```

**Logcat**

```
04-29 16:35:32.077 6391-6456/com.example.android.justjava E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
04-29 16:38:13.239 6391-6391/com.example.android.justjava E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 6391
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5496)
    at com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.displayQuantity(MainActivity.java:88)
    at com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.increment(MainActivity.java:44)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_toppings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toppings"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_whippedCream"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_whippedCream"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whipped cream"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quantity"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="increment"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Order Summary"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_summary_tex_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_price"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="order"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/price_text_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show me your `build.gradle` and the `MainActivity` `layout.xml` file

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: You are trying to set an integer value on quantityTextView.setText(number) 
change the line quantityTextView.setText(String.valueof(number))

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: Just so that I can try and solve this myself next time, how did you know where the problem was? Did you read through the whole MainActivity.java, or was there something in the Logcat?